How to configure .NET to use the system proxy?
I work in a corporate network. It requires a connection through a proxy to connect to the internet. The development occours on windows. How to configure dotnet, so dotnet restore and dotnet tool restorte use the system proxy?
I know it is possible to set evironment variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY. Problem is, they mess up other programs.
Also setting the proxy hard in the nuget config isn't an option, because I work on multiple machines and every password change would be a nightmare.
